# delegate and cancellationtoken troubleshooting

Tags: delegates, nullreferenceexception, anonymous-function, cancellation-token

I can't understand why I'm getting *System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* exception.
I would like to pass the delegate ConnectAsyncDelegate to Commit function.
It's necessary to use CancellationToken, so I have delegate which gets CancellationToken then I pass it to Commit.
In Commit function is created *cts.Token* and is passed to *method(cts.Token)*.
In this part I am getting the error `return await method(cts.Token);`

```
Func<CancellationToken, Task<int?>> ConnectAsyncDelegate = async cts => await tunnel.sslStreamServer.ReadAsync(buffer, cts);

int? response = await Tunneling.Commit(method: ConnectAsyncDelegate);

public static async Task<int?> Commit(Func<CancellationToken, Task<int?>>? method = null, Action<CancellationToken>? action = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using (var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(Settings.IoTimeout))
        {
            var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(timeout.Token, cancellationToken);
            try
            {
                cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                action?.Invoke(cts.Token);
                if (method != null)
                {
                    return await method(cts.Token);
                }
                return -1;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException oex)
            {
                if (timeout.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    throw new OperationCanceledException("Timed out waiting the operation.", oex, timeout.Token);
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have checked that cts.Token and method is not null but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just missed this things
`tunnel.sslStreamServer.ReadAsync(buffer, cts);` to
`tunnel.sslStreamClient.ReadAsync(buffer, cts);`